# Integrating Moodle with Custom Web-Application - Session and Cookie name

Tags: php, session, cookies, moodle

I have my custom web-application. Now, I want to integrate moodle with my custom web-application.

I have a problem in User - `Signup / Login` Form.

I already have registration and `log in` form in my website. All I want now, is to know what `encryption` system does `moodle` use to store password, and what are session and cookie name, that are set after successful `Login / Registration`.

Password that is stored in moodle `mdl_user` table is `$2y$10$.G0wQDpf6UxF1UgV/xFn/elDDRRPnxkAHESR1p9016Dau5E/tLiUK` . I am not able to understand what kind of encryption system it is. Someone recommended me , moodle uses `md5`, but after looking to moodle `password hash`, it doesn't look like `md5`.

Kindly do not suggest me authentication plugin or other format. I am stuck with my approach, Even though in many circumstances, it is categorized as wrong approach, but I would let it go and run my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle uses MD5 hash for password encription. If you have enabled the password salt then it will append the salt and then encrypt it using MD5.

```
if (isset($CFG->passwordsaltmain)) {
 return md5($password.$CFG->passwordsaltmain);
 } else {
 return md5($password);

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool! Where can i find value for `$CFG->passwordsaltmain`. Also, Do you know what are session and cookie name used in moodle once user is logged in. Thanks

Comment: I think that since 2.5 the default function is crypt (and indeed, the hashing looks like an output from crypt). Have a look here: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/password_compat/lib/password.php#L196